# Two forms on same page and php script is not working

Tags: php, sql

there are two forms one is registration form and another is sign in form .When am registring with registration form its div element is fetching message from php using isset funtion but when i am doing same thing with sign in it is redirecting page to homepage please help what can i do if am trying to match database if not matched it will fetch value from php and show in the div as in the code

```
    <?php 
    if (!empty($_POST['finish'])) {
       //do something here;
    include'php/signup.php';
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['go'])) {
       include'php/signin.php';
    }
    ?>      

    <html>
    <head>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/homepage.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/signup.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/signup.js"></script>        
    <script>
    function hideMessage() {
        document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
    };
    setTimeout(hideMessage, 5000);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body >
    <!--row starts here -->

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-2">
       <div class="container">

      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Sign Up</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Sign In</li>            
      </ul>        
      <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">            
    <div id="message"><?php if(isset($message)) echo $message; ?></div>
    <ul id="registration-step">
    <li id="account" class="highlight">Account</li>
    <li id="password">Password</li>
    <li id="general">Nick Name</li>
    </ul>
    <form name="frmRegistration" id="registration-form" method="post">
    <div id="account-field">
    <span id="email-error" class="registration-error"></span>
    <div><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="demoInputBox" placeholder="E-mail"/></div>
    </div>        
    <div id="password-field" style="display:none;">
    <span id="password-error" class="registration-error"></span>
    <div><input type="password" name="password" id="user-password" class="demoInputBox" placeholder="Password"required /></div>        
    </div>        
    <div id="general-field" style="display:none;">        
    <div><input type="text" name="nickname" id="display-name" class="demoInputBox" placeholder="Nick Name"/></div>        
    </div>
    <div>
    <input class="btnAction" type="button" name="back" id="back" value="Back" style="display:none;">
    <input class="btnAction" type="button" name="next" id="next" value="Next" >
    <input class="btnAction" type="submit" name="finish" id="finish" value="Finish"  style="display:none;">
    </div>
    </form>        
    </div>     
     <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    <div id="signinmsg"><?php if(isset($msg1)) echo $msg1; ?></div> 
    <form  name="signin"method="post">
        <input type="text" name="signinemail"class="demoInputBox"placeholder="E-mail">
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" class="demoInputBox"name="signinpass"placeholder="Password"><br><br>
    <input class="btnAction" type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Go.." >     
    </form>
    </div> 
    </div>
    </div>        
    <!--this row ends here -->        
  </body>        
    </html>
```

Comment: try isset instead of !empty

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking if `isset` and not `!empty`

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['finish'])) {
       //do something here;
    include'php/signup.php';
    }

    if (isset($_POST['go'])) {
       include'php/signin.php';
    }
?>
```

Comment: <div id="signinmsg"><?php if(isset($msg1)) echo $msg1; ?></div>  i want msg here if user values match with database but it is redirecting page pls help

Comment: Check your script to see if there's any `header()` function making it redirect. I will not also be able to tell exactly what is happening if I am not seeing your codes to ascertain where you have some mix ups.